# sIFR selected text background

Tags: text, background, sifr, selected

It seems to me that sIFRed text when selected allways have black background. My site design is dark (mostly black). So when use select sIFRed text it looks like nothing happens, it is selected but no one can see that cause both site and selected text background are black. Normal text have white or some kind of dark-green color depending on font color.

How to change color of selected text background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all those years things has changed. Best way to do it now is to omit sIFR, cufon and others and use just CSS @font-face. Best with fallbacks e.g.:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url('fonts/font-name.eot');
    src: url('fonts/font-name.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/font-name.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/font-name.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/font-name.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/font-name.svg#fontname') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Always fresh things about that can be (and probably will be in a future) found at http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://yourpalmark.com/2007/08/13/changing-selection-color-on-dynamic-textfields/

use this and compile your font .swf again. but i would use cufon, sifr is too laggy!

Comment: When I put this flash solutoion into fla file it causes errors while exporting movie. Where should I put this code?

Cufon is no solution - it does not support selecting at all.

Comment: well its to complicated to explain in the comments. take a look at how a oop programming works in flash, Object-Oriented Scrollbar: Part 1 and 2 will help you http://www.gotoandlearn.com/ or you use @font-face